# Android ADB can't ALWAYS see the phone device

Tags: android

I have read all the relative threads about ADB not recognizing devices. My case though is different: ADB sometimes "sees" my phone (Samsung Galaxy) and other times NOT. No matter how many times I kill and restart the ADB service or I disconnect and reconnect the device from/to the PC. Quite an unstable situation here. You know, it's one of these things that drives you crazy. That's why I resorted to your help.

Has anyone had this exact problem and resolved it once for all?

More info:

1. The PC has never a problem recognizing the device.
2. I try with both the standard SDK adb.exe and the Universal ADB driver adb.exe.
3. Either of the above have no problem recognizing the emulator.

Comment: I know you're frustrated and tired of reading through answers that haven't helped, but still it would be helpful if you stated specifically some of the things you've tried. It would help us to better pinpoint the problem.

Comment: I use the usual way: Connect the device to PC via USB.
But again, the emphasis is on ALWAYS, i.e. why has ADB STOPPED recognizing the device although it is certainly connected to the PC, i.e. it appears in Windows Explorer

Comment: OK, so have you tried disabling USB debugging in the developer options on the device, then re-enabling it so your PC has to recognize and allow the device again?

Comment: Yes, I did that too. I worked once but it was accidental.
Please see the (long) Q&A below.

Answer (score 0):

Couple things.

1) it's a dumb suggestion but sometimes its as simple as this. Did you try more than one cable?

2) If yes, then try this.  try as many times as you have to get it connected since u said "ALWAYS" so it does work sometimes. When it does work, open terminal or command line and run the following commands.

(make sure device is connected when you do this AND you are on the **same wifi network**)

```
adb tcpip 5555
```

then **disconnect your phone** and run the following command:

```
adb connect YOUR_LOCAL_IP
```

do this many times, this is wireless adb connection and if this works, its something with ADB or your computer and not the phone.

Let me know if it works. I might have more ideas depending on what result you get

============ EDIT ============

I believe it's offline because it says `8080`. I just did the same with my phone and I get the following:

[image: note: port 5555]

Try this: disconnect phone physically (if connected) and all other devices and make sure by doing: `adb disconnect`.

then, do `adb kill-server`

then, on your phone, go to `Developer Options` and **uncheck** `USB debugging`.

then, right underneath that options, there is `Revoke USB debugging authorizations` options. select and revoke all devices

then, **check** `USB debugging`

then, back on your computer, run `adb start-server`

then, try reconnecting with the steps I said before. make sure port is `5555`

**when you run the `adb connect` command, make sure to add the port at the end.

example: adb connect 10.0.0.15:5555**

Hope this works.

Comment: 1) I have no other cable that I can use but, as I told, the USB connection to the PC works perfectly within a few seconds *everytime*. So there's definitely no connection problem.

Comment: 2) I have connected the device via Wi-Fi, I used WebDAV to create a server and then tried "adb tcpip 5555" and "adb connect <IP_address>: and it worked, i.e. ADB is connected to it (nice!) but then "adb devices" gives the following info "192.168.1.4:8080 offline". I wonder why "offline" and how to make it "online" ... 
Any ideas for further action?

Comment: I did uncheck and re-check "USB debugging" as you suggested. I don't have "Revoke USB debugging authorizations" options, though. 
Then I set the WebDAV port to 5555 and re-created the server, now as "192.168.1.4:5555". This looked quite promising indeed, only that this time "adb tcpip 5555" doesn't work!  I keep receiving the message "error: device '(null)' not found" ! 
I think we are progressing ... What's the next step?

Comment: that error comes because first you have to connect it via cable and when its connected, run `adb tcpip 5555`. this way, when you unplug it and run `adb connect 192.168.1.4:5555` it will actually connect. this process is necessary for non-rooted phones. rooted phone doesnt require that extra step

Comment: OK, I reconnected ADB to 192.168.1.4:5555 successfully. But it shows again "offline".
On the other hand, ADB this time recognized the phone!
So, maybe this is the medicine for the ADB "instability": One should unselect and then re-select "USB debugging". At least, I hope that this is the case!

Comment: ok good im glad that worked. IF you want to try something else, you can try this. when your phone gives debugging permission to a computer, it creates and saves a unique key for that computer. so it know it was previously connected. What you can do is delete that (this is basically same as doing `Revoke USB debugging authorizations` since you don't have that option).  This file is located here: `/data/misc/adb/adb_key`. If you delete the file and try connecting with a cable, you should get a popup on your phone asking if you want to give permission to this computer, say always and yes

Comment: OK. Thank you very much for helping!
(And I'm sorry stackoverflow.com team and member fellows for that quasi-chat)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111300/discussion-between-apostolos-and-smit-patel).